# Cartesian coordinate from projection on two planes

Tags: geometry

**Context :**

I have a matrix of sensor, and I need to get the cartesian coordinate of each points returned by the sensors.

**Input :**

The field of view on the plane Oxz : $\alpha$ from the axis Oz and the number of sensors in that plane
The field of view on the plane Oyz : $\beta$ from the axis Oz and the number of sensors in that plane
The distance to the point

**Question**

How can I have the cartesian coordinate of each point?

*Note*:
I haven't done any geometry in something like 10 years, i'm a bit rusty, I might be missing a point.

When i'm in the plane Oxz or Oyz, it's just a simple projection.
For example, in the plane 0xz $x=-sin(\alpha)$ and $z=cos(\alpha)$
But when we are not in these planes, I can't see how to project the point

Edit : added a picture trying to represent everything
A is point I want the coordinate
On the left plane Oxz is drawn, on the right plane Oyz
$\alpha$ is the angle between CO and the Oz axis
$\beta$ is the angle between BO and the Oz axis

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xald4.png)

Comment: Picture added, I hope it's clear enough

Comment: So in relation to the picture, what is the input? What is given and what is sought? In general, knowing the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the distance between points $O$ and $A$, you can find the three dimensional  coordinates of $A$. Is this what you want?

Comment: Indeed, input is  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the distance between O and A, and I need the coordinate of A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this one, I would just look at the picture and argue geometrically, without really using linear algebra.

I hope it is ok to assume we are in the upper-half space. Then your angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and I can safely use $\tan$. If not, one can slightly manipulate the signs in the formulas to get them a bit more general or simply rewrite the formulas in cosines and sines.

So the plane defined by the three points $A, B, C$ is orthogonal to the $z$ axis and let's say it intersects it in point $D$. Then you have a rectangular pyramid $OABDC$ with $OD$ orthogonal to the plane defined by the rectangle $ABDC$. This means that, $OD$ is orthogonal to all lines in the plane $ABDC$. Therefore, the three triangles $ODC$, $\, ODB$ and $ODA$ are right-angled with $\angle \, DOC = \alpha$ and $\angle \, DOB = \beta$.

The coordinates you need are 
$x = CD = AB$ also $y = BD = AC$ and $z=OD$. Then,

1. since $ODC$ is right-angled 
   $$\frac{x}{z} = \tan{\alpha}$$  $$x = z \, \tan{\alpha}$$
2. since $ODB$ is right-angled 
   $$\frac{y}{z} = \tan{\beta}$$ $$y = z \, \tan{\beta}$$
3. In rectangle $ABDC$ triangle say $ABD$ is right-angled so by Pythagoras' theorem
   $$DA^2 = x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \, \big(\tan^2{\alpha} + \tan^2{\beta}\big)$$
4. By Pythagoras' theorem for triangle $ODA$
   $$OA^2 = OD^2 + DA^2 = z^2 + z^2 \, \big(\tan^2{\alpha} + \tan^2{\beta}\big) = z^2 \, \big(1 + \tan^2{\alpha} + \tan^2{\beta}\big)$$
   so combnied with points 1 and 2
   $$z = \frac{|OA|}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2{\alpha} + \tan^2{\beta}}}$$ 
   $$x = \frac{|OA| \, \tan{\alpha}}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2{\alpha} + \tan^2{\beta}}}$$ 
   $$y = \frac{|OA| \, \tan{\beta}}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2{\alpha} + \tan^2{\beta}}}$$

Comment: Great thanks, I could have done that a few years back, but not anymore.